# Writing to flask database in dockerized celery app

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery

I was wondering what the best approach is to achieve this

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./services/website
    volumes:
      - ./services/website/src:/usr/src/app/src
      - ./data/cntautomation_logs:/var/log/cntautomation_logs
    expose:
      - 5010
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DEPLOYMENT_TYPE=production
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbit_mongodb
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        - ./data/db_logs:/var/log/postgresql
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=user
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        - POSTGRES_DB=database.db
  nginx:
    build: ./services/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx_logs:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    volumes:
      - ./data/rabbitmq_logs:/var/log/rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"

  rabbit_mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/rabbit_mongodb_logs:/var/log/mongodb
    command: 
      - '--logpath'
      - '/var/log/mongodb/rabbit_mongodb_log.log'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  worker:
    build: ./services/worker
    user: nobody
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - ./services/worker/app:/usr/src/app/app
      - ./data/worker_logs:/var/log/worker
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
      - web
      - rabbit_mongodb
  
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I have a docker compose file like such. I was wondering what the best method is to write to my postgres db in the celery worker container.

The common solution I see for this is creating a make_celery function that passes in the application context, but I don't see how this would work when celery and flask are split into separate containers. One solution I thought about that I am not sure would even work, would be to pass the application context as a pickled object when ever a task is called in a flask route, then execute the task with the application context.
eg.

```
task.py:
@task(name="task.add")
def add(app, x, y):
    with app.app_context():
        # Write to db
        return x + y

views.py:
@app.route('/add')
def add():
    celery.send_task('task.add', args=[app, 1, 2])
```

I see three problems with the approach though:

1. I don't know how I would write to the db with a celery beat scheduled task.
2. Would I create a replica of flask db models in the worker container and instantiate a new sqlalchemy instance? Or maybe pass the model that needs writing as a pickled object just like the app context?
3. I have not seen anyone do it, so it probably is not even an acceptable approach

I don't really like this solution at all, but im not sure what the standard approach would be

Comment: If I understood correctly, models source code are not shared between the "web" and the "worker". Why that? Can't you create a "model" file and share it between web and worker?

Comment: Fair enough. Do something like creating volumes between the containers?. Currently I have my web app structured something like web: {app1: {views, models, forms}, app2: {views, models, forms}, ... etc } so it would be a little tricky to mount volumes. And what about passing app context? Do you think the above solution makes any sense? Im surprised theres not many comments online about this, it kind of seems like a fairly regular thing someone might have to do. Would it be overall easier to just move the celery worker into my web app container?

Comment: _Do something like creating volumes between the containers?_
Nooo... just import your models in the worker app. Make the models module availabel for both app before containerizing the application.

_And what about passing app context?_
You don't need to pass app_context arround. Just create a new Flask app in the worker side, using the same configuration, and use the app_context of this new app